# How can I configure an Azure alert to notify me when an IIS website in a VM goes down?

Tags: azure, web, iis, azure-application-insights, alerts

I am looking to see if anyone has achieved the above and if they have done so using Application Insights or another method. I would like to be able to notify a group by email when a website on a hosted VM become unhealthy.

I have looked into different ways to complete this task but wanted to see if anyone had and what their thoughts were on the best way to take it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a public facing website you can use [Application Insights availability tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/availability-overview)

> After you've deployed your web app or website, you can set up recurring tests to monitor availability and responsiveness. Application Insights sends web requests to your application at regular intervals from points around the world. It can alert you if your application isn't responding or responds too slowly.
>
> You can set up availability tests for any HTTP or HTTPS endpoint that's accessible from the public internet. You don't have to make any changes to the website you're testing. In fact, it doesn't even have to be a site that you own. You can test the availability of a REST API that your service depends on.

The next step would be to create [an availability alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/availability-alerts) to notify per email about any issues

[image]